# Searching specific folder within google drive base on cell value given in the Googlesheet and want to save its complete url in the googlesheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google sheet to keep my data. The data is confidential and I can not share it here. The dummy data sample is looks like this.
[image]

The (1)- is registration number, which I want to look into the Google Drive. This registration number has the same folder name within the google drive that contains the additional information about the registration number. So, I want to find that folder within the google drive and once it found, I need to store the path of that folder in the sheet as given in the column "G" Photoreport. I have millions of data and I want to search this data row by row and keep the path of each row in the same column. If path not found there should be a statement which will show me that "Path Not Found". I have tried this code but is not working.

```
    function SearchFiles() {
  //Please enter your search term in the place of Letter
  var searchFor ='title contains "Letter"';
  var names =[];
  var fileIds=[];
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();// To get FileId of the file
    fileIds.push(fileId);
    var name = file.getName();
    names.push(name);

  }

  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    Logger.log(names[i]);
    Logger.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileIds[i]);

  }

}
```

Please help me in this problem. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "title contains 'Letter'"?  It says to use single quotes in the query string.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the issue? You can't find the files that you already have the URL for?

Comment: I would use getFoldersByName()

Answer (score 0):

#### Find Folders

```
function findFolders() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Name');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(!r[6] && r[2]) {
      let folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(r[2]);
      let folder = [];
      while (folders.hasNext()) {
        folder.push(folders.next());
      }
      if((folder.length > 1)) {
        sh.getRange(i + 2,7).setValue(`${folder.length} folders with name ${r[2]}`)
      } else if(folder.length == 0 ) {
        sh.getRange(i + 2, 7).setValue(`Folder name: ${r[2]} not found`);
      } else if (folder.length == 1) {
        sh.getRange(i + 2, 7).setValue(folder[0].getId());//I would prefer having the id of the folder because going to folder with the id is very easy with getFolderById();
      }
    }
  });
}
```